# DataGrid is partially updated when bound to DataTable in code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatable, datagrid

I have a WPF window that has a DataGrid as one of its children.  The number of columns in the DataGrid is only determined at runtime.  Here is the code for the DataGrid in my window.xaml file:

```
 <DataGrid Name="pathLossGrid" 
                 AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding }"
                 VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                 HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                 GridLinesVisibility="All">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <local:PathLossCell/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

In the Windows.xaml.cs, I've declared a dependency property for a DataTable property:

```
public static DependencyProperty PathLossTableProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(PathLossTable), typeof(DataTable), typeof(PathLossSelector));

public DataTable PathLossTable
{
     get => (DataTable)GetValue(PathLossTableProperty);
     set => SetValue(PathLossTableProperty, value);
}
```

I should note at this point that each cell in the DataGrid is of a custom user control type, which I have called a PathLossCell in my example code and that user control is a simple grid with two columns:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding S2pId }"
               MinWidth="50"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="3 0 0 0"
            Command="{Binding SelectS2pFileCommand}">
        <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
            <ContentControl Content="{DynamicResource icon_plus}"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </Button>            
</Grid>
```

the constructor of my Windows.xaml.cs file calls the following method:

```
public void InitPathLossTable()
{
    if (PathLossTable == null && SelectedPortList != null)
    {
        var tmpTable = new DataTable("pathLossTable");
        foreach (var port in SelectedPortList)
        {
            var portLoss = 0;
            DataColumn newColumn = new DataColumn($"{port} (Max Loss= {portLoss} dB)");
            newColumn.DataType = typeof(PathLossCell);
            tmpTable.Columns.Add(newColumn);
        }

        //add default row
        DataRow newRow = tmpTable.NewRow();
        for (int col = 0; col < tmpTable.Columns.Count; col++)
        {
            newRow[col] = new PathLossCell() { S2pFile = "no data", RowId = 0, ColumnId = col, PortName = tmpTable.Columns[col].ColumnName };
        }

        tmpTable.Rows.Add(newRow);

        PathLossTable = tmpTable;
        pathLossGrid.DataContext = PathLossTable.DefaultView;
    }
}
```

Based on my research on this site and other sources, this is the way to bind a DataTable to a DataGrid and what I expected to see in my window is a grid with 2 or 3 columns (depending on the number of items in the SelectedPortList and one row of default PathLossCell items.  What I see when I run this code is a table that has the right number of columns (and the correct column headers), but only the cell in position [0,0] has the PathLossCell control in it and all the other cells display the fully qualified type string for PathLossCell and somehow an extra row:
[image]

I've tried setting the binding directly in xaml to: ItemsSource="{Binding PathLossTable.DefaultView }" with no discernable difference in the result and not also not including the DataGridTemplateColumn definition, in which case I don't see even the one instance of the PathLossCell user control in the first column.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Edit after applying fix suggested by @BionicCode:

Replaced the DataGrid.Columns template with DataGrid.CellStyle as suggested and here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define a column then you are doing just that, defining a column explicitly. This is not to be confused with a `DataTemplate` e.g. for all cells.

If you set `DataGrid.AutogenerateColumns` to `true` then the `DataGrid` will generate the column definitions for you by adding a `DataGridTextColumn` to the `DataGrid.Columns` collection for each column. As the name `DataGridTextColumn` suggests, it only displays text (the `object.ToString` value of the cell's item) as the `ControlTemplate` of the `DataGridCell` will simply contain a `TextBlock`. If you need a more sophisticated column layout you can define a `DataGridTemplateColumn` which supports a custom column layout by providing a cell template - *only* for the current column. That's why the name `DataGridTemplateColumn` contains the word "Template". It's not a template for all columns but for the particular column definition.

To create a default template for all cells of the `DataGrid` you simply provide a `Style` for the `DataGridCell` and assign it to the `DataGrid.CellStyle` property.

Regarding your `DataGrid.ItemsSource` bindig, you don't have to explicitly bind to the `DataTable.DataView` property. The binding will automatically get the data view.

```xml
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=PathLossTable}">
  <DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridCell">

            <!-- The DataContext is the current cell value (not the row item) -->
            <local:PathLossCell/>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: thank you.  Your explanation makes perfect sense and the Cell Style fixed the main problem.  I've updated the post with a picture after applying the fix.  The styling problem is definitely resolved.  Now I just have to figure out where the extra row is coming from.

Comment: The blank row at the very bottom?

Comment: yes - there should only be one row in the table after the InitPathLossTable method is called since I only add one newRow to the table, unless the table always has 1 row by default?

Comment: Ok. The blank row is automatically added to enable the user to create a new entry. The user can double click this blank row and start editing it. You can disable this feature by setting `DataGrid.CanUserAddRows` to `false`.

Comment: while setting the DataGridCell style template did solve the visual problem of displaying the user control in the cells correctly, it seems that cells displayed in the datagrid are just default instance of a PathLossCell and not the properly initialized ones that I put in the DataTable.  This is really confusing to me since the datagrid.itemsource is definitely bound to the PathLossTable.  I know that because if I change the number of columns in the PathLossTable, I see the right number of columns in the datagrid and with the correct column headers, but the row data is not correct

Comment: *"cells displayed in the datagrid are just default instance of a PathLossCell and not the properly initialized ones that I put in the DataTable"* - You must not add them manually because that's what the template is for. You only have to assign the correct bindings to the relevant properties inside the template to initialize the control with data from the row item. The template is not just a layout template in a way that it contains place holders. In WPF ControlTemplates and DataTemplates are real instances.

Comment: Elements inside those templates are instantiated by invoking the default constructor. Data is set via data binding. You can do this in code-behind too, but this is usually not necessary. Doing it  in XAML saves you a lot of code and makes your code more efficient - because you don't have to deal with iterations and initializations.

Comment: Again, the `DataContext` of the `DataGridCell` is the cell data - and not the row data. If your `PathLossCell` is designed for row data then your design is wrong. Like the name "PathLossCell" correctly suggests, the control must display the data of the current *cell*. For example: when `PathLossCell` has a property `Value` to display an e.g. text value, then you would have to bind it explicitly to the `DataContext` (the cell's value): `<PathLossCell Value="{Binding}" />`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can avoid this explicit binding by simply binding the internals of the `PathLossCell` to the control's `DataContext`.  In other words, `PathLossCell` must be able to display *all* individual values of each individual cell that are provided by a `DataTable`. Because you use auto-generation of data columns, the mapping is handled by the `DataGrid`. The `DataGrid` just reads one cell value from the `DataTable` and creates a `DataGridCell` container based on the template for this cell value. In your case, the cell template defines a `PathLossCell` as the content presenter.

Comment: If you have different value types that you have to display differently you may have to introduce additional content presenters like the `PathLossCell`. Also in this case overriding the DtaGridCell is not the correct way. You would have to manually provide column definitions by handling the `DataGrid.Autogenerated` event. If your cell values are simple text presentations, then you don't need the `PathLossCell` at all and can reduce the complexity of your code.

Comment: all the cells in all the columns have the same exact type, which is the PathLossCell, but the PathLossCell is combination of a button and a textblock and additional properties that are set (but not displayed).  I auto generate the columns in the constructor for the view that has the DataGrid and add a default row to the table, but cells in that row should have different properties based on the columns, but when I examine the cells at runtime, they all have the same property values (what comes out of the PathLossCell default constructor)

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood the concept correctly. or maybe I misunderstood your comment. To me it sounds like you are adding PathLossCell instances to your columns manually. But you  shouldn't do it that way. Because you have defined the PathLossCell ainside the cell's template it is automatically created for you. And of course this causes the XAML parser to call the default constructor, as the XAML parser will *always* do whenever it creates any instances.

Comment: That's why I wrote in some comment that you have to initilaize the cell via data binding (bind the PathLossCell inside the DataTemplate to the DataContext). And if the data source is not always the same property path (which would require a binding with a dynamic Binding.Path - if that would be possible), you must follow a different path. It's really not clear what you are trying to do. Because it appears you are doing something wrong and that you actually donm't really want to define a cell template, but something different.

Comment: To make the purpose of the cell template more clear hopefully, the default cell template contains a simple TextBlock where the Text property binds to the cell value., which is either directly a string or the result of the object.ToString() call. Now it's not clear why you want to chgange this. You usually define atemplate for individual columns if you want to show data differently (non textual or using a more complex layout).